# Mysql returning clause equivalent

Tags: mysql

I am a complete newbie to MySql so please be gentle.

Is there an equivalent of the `RETURNING` clause in Oracle or the `Inserted'/'Deleted` tables in SQL Server in MySQL?  What I want to do is the following:

- Delete a set of rows from table A
- Insert the deleted set of rows into table B.

  Please help!

Thanks

Comment: Are you going to do delete/update in a trigger?

Comment: @Korhan, Not in a trigger, but within an SP.  I  know within a trigger you can get old/new.  But I need this within an SP

Comment: You **cannot** do both insertion and deletion in a single query @Cpat. Check my answer below...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't do both insertion and deletion in **one query**, but you can do it all in one **transaction** if you are using a transactional store engine (like InnoDB). Moreover, `RETURNING` is supported by Oracle and PostgreSQL but not by MySQL and therefore you need to write separate `delete` and `insert` statements.

Using a transaction however, will guarantee that only the successfully copied data will be deleted from tableA. Consider the following:

```
begin transaction;
insert into tableB select * from tableA where 'your_condition_here';
delete from tableA where 'your_condition_here';
commit;
```

Comment: That is what I am finding as well.  NO equivalent clause in MySql for what I want to do. Oh well, 2 separate statements is it then.  thank you for your help

Comment: Thank you for verifying my answer. I'm glad that my answer was helpful.

Comment: Note `insert ... returning` is supported in MariaDB 10.5 and newer; but not Oracle MySQL AFAIK. https://mariadb.com/kb/en/insertreturning/

Answer (score 0):

Why not insert the rows to be deleted from table A in table B and then delete the rows from table A? you can achieve that like this:

```
insert into tableB select * from tableA where condition;
```

and then

```
delete from tableA where condition.
```

Comment: Ideally I'd like to just run the one statement. something similar to what you do in Sql Server -> Delete from table1 output deleted.col1, deleted.col2 into table2(col3, col4);