# How to UPDATE and SELECT at the same time in MySQL

Tags: mysql, select

With a relationship with this question [How UPDATE and SELECT at the same time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2934369/how-update-and-select-at-the-same-time)
and with this code:

```
UPDATE table SET foo=1 WHERE boo=2

SELECT * from table WHERE foo=1 AND boo=2
```

How can I UPDATE and SELECT at the same time with MySQL?

It seems the person asking the existing question uses PostgreSQL. How can I do that in MySQL? It seems there is no `returning` command in MySQL.

Comment: Do not think there is anything for MySQL.

Comment: I'm just asking if its possible so I would not be creating two queries... for the sake of creating optimal code(or if its really makes the execution more faster..)

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, RETURNING is not supported by MySQL and therefore you need to write separate statements.

As an alternative, you can rely on a stored procedure.

The question of whether MySQL has a returning clause equivalent, in general, was addressed here: [Mysql returning clause equivalent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9583353/mysql-returning-clause-equivalent)